# CSS aggregates generating but not loading (core and AdvAgg), but JS aggregates load fine

Tags: 7, css-js-aggregation

I'm trying to set up aggregation and compression on my site, but am having problems. When I enable aggregation, either through core or through AdvAgg, it seems that aggregates are being generated for both CSS/JS files when I check sites/default/files, but only the JS aggregates are actually being loaded. When I check my page sources, the browser is displaying all of the original CSS files as though an aggregate had not been generated/enabled. I'm running Omega and a sub-theme, if that's a possible issue. Any suggestions on what to try?

EDIT: As per my comment below, the only theme option I see relating to aggregation is "Rebuild CSS and JS aggregates on every page load", and checking/unchecking it doesn't seem to have any effect. I can't seem to find anything else relating to aggregation within the theme settings.

Comment: There might be a setting in the theme that's overriding CSS aggregation.

Comment: Also see what the status report page says

Comment: The only theme option I see relating to aggregation is "Rebuild CSS and JS aggregates on every page load", and checking it doesn't seem to have any effect. Status report page says that aggregation is working fine. The files are indeed aggregating, so that's probably why it's not flagging on the status page.

Comment: You should open a support request over here https://www.drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/advagg although if core CSS isn't working that makes me think it's something that AdvAgg might not be able to fix.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, mikey.  That was my thought process though as well. Not sure if they'll be able to help since it's happening with core aggregation also, but it couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there is a "Development Extension" that is a part of the Omega theme settings. I had it enabled for a couple of the features it provides, but unchecking it caused the aggregates to start loading like normal. Guess having that enabled is what broke the aggregation. Hopefully this ends up helping somebody else eventually.